# SAML SP Metadata: Self-signed Certifcate or CA Certificate, what is the best practice?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, saml-2.0, adfs, spring-saml

I have to add a SAML implementation on a project. I decided to use Spring SAML.
I'm able to generate an Service Provider metadata file and I have to send this file to the IDP (this IDP uses ADFS) but I don't know if I should create an auto-signed key or CA signed certificate for our SP metadata file.
According to this [link](https://services.renater.fr/federation/en/certificates#federation_education-recherche_-_saml_x509_certificates_management), the best practice is to generate a self-signed certificate (x509 certificate). But I also found some topics which advice to use a CA signed certificate.

But I can't find anything on the specs.

What's the best practice ?
And if I should use a CA signed certificate, how can I obtain it?

Thanks to All

Answer (score 3):

SAML2 uses certificates just as a convenient way to handle signing and encryption keys. The SAML2 specification even states that it cannot be asumed that the certificates hasn't expired or is issued to any relevant host name.

So that's what the specification says. But in reality some IDP or SP operators require the certificates to be valid.

I'd suggest that you talk to the Idp operator and ask if they have any requirements. If they don't, go for a self signed cert.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. If I should use a CA signed certificate, which provider should I use ?